# How to set null value to variable using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, jquery-events

I'm storing an image value in the variable `first_img`:

```
var first_img = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
```

And I want to set the value `null` after the button is clicked JavaScript or jQuery.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the image or just do what you're asking, set `first_img` to `null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `src` attribute when the image is clicked:

```
$('img[alt="example"]').click(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('src');
});
```

or completely remove the `<img>` tag from the DOM:

```
$('img[alt="example"]').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: note: `$(this).removeAttr('src')` doesn't work, see my jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/duDxb/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get this at all, as it sounds kinda obvious?

```
var first_img = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');

$('button').on('click', function() {
    first_img = null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var first_img = $('<img alt="example"/>').attr('src',[...] )
 .on('click',
      function(){$(this).remove()}
  );​
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/duDxb/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:-`enter code here`
***$('img[alt="example"]').click(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('src');
});***
```